# Mathematical philosophy: intuitionistic formalism

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

What is intuitionistic formalism?

Tarski called himself an intuitionistic formalist.

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! You might want to expand a little on what you mean by 'intuitionistic formalism'; possibly by adding a link; I've heard of 'intuitionism' and 'formalism'; but not the two together - they seem to be at odds with each - which may or may not have provoked your question.

Comment: You might also consider adding why this question is important to you - perhaps you lean in one direction or another; questions with some 'body' to it tend to attract better quality answers; and links are useful for uncommon jargon.

Answer (score 3):

A sort of explanation can be found in [this review](https://jhaponline.org/jhap/article/download/13/12) by Roman Murawski of

> Alfred Tarski, Philosophy ofLanguage and Logic by Douglas Patterson

where Murawski writes:

> Patterson shows in the book that Tarski’s views were more complex than
>   they are usually taken to be. He argues that both indicated papers
>   made major contributions to representative semantics and model theory.
>   Simultaneously he shows, by careful examination of Tarski’s works,
>   that Tarskis results were in fact motivated by the expressive
>   conception of meaning. He inherited this view from his teacher
>   Stanis?aw Le´sniewski, and Tarski referred to it as “intuitionistic
>   formalism.” Intuitionistic formalism, or intuitive formalism, as it is
>   sometimes called, was the conviction that logical formulas should be
>   meaningful not only from the syntactic but also from the intuitive
>   point of view. Thus Le´sniewski claimed that every language system
>   says something about something, that statements of every formal theory
>   are endowed with meaning. He rejected the interpretation of such
>   theories as games using symbols void of meaning.